# Downgrade kernel U16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel, brightness, downgrade

I read many questions like mine but I didn't solve.
I explain my situation: 
I currently have kernel `4.13.0-26-generic` that solve Meltdown and Spectre on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

After that upgrade I can't change brightness on my lenovo t450. The percentage is always 55% and I can't change it neither by `fn` and changing percentage bar on settings.

I think that downgrading kernel to `4.10.0-42-generic` (my previous version) will fix it and I will wait for new version for meltdown that doesn't compromise brightness.

On my system if have:

```
rc  linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic
rc  linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic                               
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-40-generic                               
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic                               
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-42-lowlatency                            
ii  linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic
```

How can I downgrade to `4.10.0-42`? I fear about remove `4.13.0-26-generic` and run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: You do not have to downgrade or remove anything, although you certainly may if you wish. You select which kernel to to boot at the grub screen when you boot.

Comment: I haven't got (and like) grub screen..

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Comment: Hit escape or shift button as you boot or unhide the menu :

Comment: @Panther I don't want that screen, but I can try to load system with the previous version to see if that brightness problem is still present

Comment: @linofex yes you do. We all have. Unless you installed the ancient lilo.

Comment: yes, you want to select which kernel to boot from the grub screen. You can then set the one you like as default if you wish. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Saved or similar

Comment: After trying different versions of kernel I still have brightness problem, so the cause is not the kernel, but something else, so I will search other solutions..

Comment: Identify your hardware and ask a new question

Comment: already fixed the problem creating a new `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and add some options about my graphic card